# What are good Linux/Unix books for an advancing user?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

Are there any good books for a relatively new but not totally new *nix user to get a bit more in depth knowledge (so no "Linux for dummies")?  For the most part, I'm not looking for something to read through  from start to finish.  Rather, I'd rather have something that I can pick up and read in chunks when I need to know how to do something or whenever I have one of those "how do I do that again?" moments.  Some areas that I'd like to see are:

- command line administration
- bash scripting
- programming (although I'd like something that isn't just relevant for C programmers)

I'd like this to be as platform-independent as possible (meaning it has info that's relevant for any linux distro as well as BSD, Solaris, OS X, etc), but the unix systems that I use the most are OS X and Debian/Ubuntu.  So if I would benefit the most from having a more platform-dependent book, those are the platforms to target.

If I can get all this in one book, great, but I'd rather have a bit more in-depth material than coverage of **everything**.  So if there are any books that cover just one of these areas, post it.  Hell, post it even if it's not relevant to any of those areas and you think it's something that a person in my position should know about.

Comment: Many of the unix books are quite relevant across versions - Linus used Stevens' Advanced Programming in the Unix environment as a guide to the minutae of the Unix API's as he was developing the system services code for linux.

Comment: You can go through Squid Proxy Server 3.1: Beginner's Guide book. For more info https://www.packtpub.com/squid-proxy-server-31-beginners-guide/book

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've wiki'd this post - could those with sufficient rep add in items to it.

System administration, general usage books

- Nemeth et. al, [Linux System Administration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131480049)
- The [Armadillo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003439) book, as mentioned by Bill The Lizard [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236838/what-are-good-linuxunix-books-for-an-advancing-user#236932).
- Anything by [Mark Sobell](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=mark+G+sobell&x=0&y=0).  He does a sort of theme-and-variations for various flavours of unix, so pick the book most appropriate to the environment in hand.  The books are quite good.  One of his was a prescribed text when I did my B.Sc.
- Stevens' [TCP/IP illustrated, vol. 1: The Protocols](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) for a comprehensive run down on how TCP/IP works in detail.
- I've never read this particular book, but many people here are recommending [Unix Power Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003307) as mentioned by [Hortitude.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236838/what-are-good-linuxunix-books-for-an-advancing-user#236858)

Programming:

- Anything by the late W. Richard Stevens, in particular [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079) and [Unix Network Programming Vol. 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) [and vol. 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130810819)
- Various classic c/unix books, such as [The Unix Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X), [Advanced Unix Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543), [Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880) and of course [K&R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).  The C/Unix books tend to go into the underlying architecture, and will give a fair degree of insight that's relevant across the board - these are the underlying mechanisms within the system.  Anyone trying to do system-level programming (basically anything using system services, no matter what the language) will find a grounding in this to be beneficial.

Specific tools (e.g. Sendmail)

Various of the books from O'Reilly and other publishers cover specific topics.  Some of the key ones are:

- The [Bat](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510292) book on sendmail - if you have occasion to experience the joys of working with [sendmail.cf](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/sendmail-as-turing-machine.txt).  If you have a choice on MTA, [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) or [qmail](http://www.qmail.org/top.html) are somewhat easier to work with (I've been using postfix since about 2000).  O'reilly publish guides to [both](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596002122) of [them](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565926285).
- Some classic works on [perl](http://www.cpan.org/): the [Camel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000278) and [Llama](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520107) books (the latter written by none other than [Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz)).
- [Sed and awk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922255).  Not sure what the critters on the cover are.  My copy went south a while ago.  While on the subject of this, [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) has also gotten a mention here and is a good book on the subject.
- [Samba](http://us3.samba.org/samba/).  [The hornbill (?)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007698) book covers this; there is also [quite](http://us3.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/) [a lot](http://us3.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-Guide/) [of](http://us3.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/toc.html) [on-line](http://us3.samba.org/samba/docs/) [documentation](http://wiki.samba.org/).
- [NFS/NIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565925106) for those using or maintaining unix or linux clients.

Some of these books have been in print for quite a while and are still relevant.  Consequently they are also often available secondhand at much less than list price.  Amazon marketplace is a good place to look for such items.  It's quite a good way to do a shotgun approach to topics like this for not much money.

As an example, in New Zealand technical books are usurously expensive due to a weak kiwi peso (as the $NZ is affectionately known in expat circles) and a tortuously long supply chain.  You could spend 20% of a week's after-tax pay for a starting graduate on a single book.  When I was living there just out of university I used this type of market a lot, often buying books for 1/4 of their list price - including the cost of shipping to New Zealand.  If you're not living in a location with tier-1 incomes I recommend this.

E-Books and on-line resources (thanks to [israkir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236838/what-are-good-linuxunix-books-for-an-advancing-user#237015) for reminding me):

- The Linux Documentation project ([www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/)), has many specific topic guides known as [HowTos](http://www.tldp.org/docs.html#howto) that also often concern third party OSS tools and will be relevant to other Unix variants.  It also has a series of [FAQ's](http://www.tldp.org/docs.html#faq) and [guides](http://www.tldp.org/guides.html).
- [Unix Guru's Universe](http://www.ugu.com/sui/ugu/warp.ugu) is a collection of unix resources with a somewhat more old-school flavour.
- Google.  There are many, many unix and linux resources on the web.  Search  strings like [unix commands](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&hs=vbh&q=unix+commands&revid=120646170&sa=X&oi=revisions_inline&resnum=0&ct=broad-revision&cd=2) or [learn unix](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&hs=vbh&q=learn+unix&revid=120646170&sa=X&oi=revisions_inline&resnum=0&ct=broad-revision&cd=3) will turn up any amount of online resources.
- [Safari](http://safari.oreilly.com/?cid=orm-nav-global).  This is a subscription service, but you can search the texts of quite a large number of books.  I can recommend this as I've used it.  They also do site licences for corporate customers.

Some of the philosophy of Unix:

- [The Art of UNIX Programming](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/) by E S Raymond (available online and in print).
- [The Practice of Programming](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/) by B W Kernighan and R Pike.

Answer (score 20):

I have found [Unix Power Tools](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003302/) to be one of the best resources for me.  It may not have a tutorial in it, but it is a great reference.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a tutorial anyway.  :)  I'd like something that's better as a reference tool.

Answer (score 15):

[The Art of Unix programming](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/) is a book that I've found helpful in the past, in spite of being a bit slanted against other non-unix platforms.

Answer (score 11):

The O'Reilly books have excellent *nix coverage. I have these:

[Learning the bash Shell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009656/index.html)
* Covers several basic *nix command line tools as well as more advanced shell scripting techniques.

[Learning the vi and Vim Editors](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529833/index.html)
* Priceless. Gave me the ability to very quickly edit or create shell scripts, configuration files, Python scripts from the shell.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend the [Armadillo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003439) book from O'Reilly for command line administration and shell scripting.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Jason,

[Unix Programming Environment](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Unix-Programming-Environment-Prentice-Hall-Software/dp/013937681X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1224968700&sr=8-1) by Kernighan and Pike will give you solid foundations on all things Unix and should cover most of your questions regarding shell command line scripting etc.

The [Armadillo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003439) book by O'Reilly will add the administration angle. It has served me well!

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest the bunch of books here:

http://www.linux.org/docs/online_books.html

good luck;)

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 4):

The aforementioned *Unix Power Tools* is a must. Other classics are *sed&awk* and *Mastering Regular Expressions*.
I also like some books from the O'Reilly "Cookbook" series:

- [Bash Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526784) by Albing et al.
- [Linux Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006403) by Carla Schroder
- [Linux Networking Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102488) by Carla Schroder

Answer (score 4):

The [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) is the only book that really allows the reader to grok bash scripting. You need that ability to fully understand how to start/stop daemons and to automate a lot of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In my opinion, you will learn more just by messing around with what you find interesting on a *nix box.  It is a waste of time to read about BIND if you have no interest in networks.

Comment: why didnt my image post? http://img56.imageshack.us/img56/6668/0596005288500jx2.gif

Comment: Depends what you're doing.  I've just got a fairly simple home network and I set up BIND to do internal name resolution.  I've also got an email system dating back to UUCP days where I've been using Postfix since about 2000, smail from 1995-1999 and UUPC from 1991-1995.

Comment: NXC - thanks. Quick question - why not use /etc/hosts ?

Comment: Legacy systems - I have unix mailbox file archives going back to the 1990s and had a dial-up connection until 2002 or so.  The network has a local MTA and DNS cache, although with a broadband connection these days you could probably just use the ones at the ISP.

Answer (score 2):

[The AWK Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020107981X)

Not only introduces to the versatile tool that `awk` is, but also gives an insight about the Unix based philosophy and some `awk` 'design-patterns'.

Answer (score 1):

Big agreement for *Essential System Adminstration* and *Unix Power Tools*.

Also, whichever editor you prefer, vim or emacs, learn it back & forth.  If you like vim, then get Steve Oualline's vim book.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Ubuntu and Linux in general, a good book:

- [Hacking Ubuntu by Neal Krawetz](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_ss_w_h_?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hacking+ubuntu&x=0&y=0)
- [Linux Annoyances for Geeks by Michael Jang](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_ss_w_h_?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Linux+annoyances+for+geeks&x=0&y=0)

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Kochan's "Unix Shell Programming" and "Exploring the Unix System"

Answer (score 1):

- sed & awk Dougherty and robbins
- Mastering regular expression Jeffrey Friedl
- Linux in a nutshell to look things up, although most of the info is also in manpages
- Vim by Steve Oualline