# What does the extern keyword mean?

Tags: c, objective-c, extern

What does the `extern` keyword mean? I've seen that in front of an function declaration like

```
extern void DoFoo ...
```

Comment: Saw `extern` in an objective C .h file declaring a pointer to an `NSString`, the string was defined with an `@""` convenience constructor in the corresponding .m (implementation) file.

Comment: Found this link very useful - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable

Comment: Possible duplicate: [3 questions about extern used in a Objective-C project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7330048/45249)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`extern` gives a name *external linkage*. This means that the object or function is accessible through this name from other translation units in the program. For functions, this is the default linkage in any case so its usage (in this context) is usually redundant.

Answer (score 41):

The extern keyword declares a variable or function and specifies that it has external linkage (its name is visible from files other than the one in which it's defined). When modifying a variable, extern specifies that the variable has static duration (it is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends). The variable or function may be defined in another source file, or later in the same file. Declarations of variables and functions at file scope are external by default.

You can find a [more complete description here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/).

Answer (score 4):

For Beginners,

Initially I was confused to learn that, "**the extern keyword declares a variable or function and specifies that it has external linkage** " by @Romain Hippeau.

Now I understood that, we will be able to share our variables with other classes through extern keyword.

For Example:
Notification.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 extern const NSString* notificationConstant;
```

Notification.m

```
 #import "Notification.h"
 const NSString* notificationConstant = @"NotificationConstant";
```

By importing notification.h in any of my other classes, I can read the value of string NotificationConstant.

Without extern keyword For Notification constant will create following error.
[image]