# Xcode - Apple Mach-O Linker errors when loading sound in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I currently have my app setup like this:

I set an `extern` variable in the AppDelegate.h because I've read they act as a global variable. Also added AudioToolbox framework.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

extern SystemSoundID tapSoundID;

@end
```

Next I added my code to load the tap sound in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching method because I want the sound to be loaded as soon as the app's done starting.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Load Tap Sound
    NSURL *tapSoundPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tap" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)tapSoundPath, &tapSoundID);
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Made sure to import the `AppDelegate.h` class in my title screen view controller.

**TitleScreen.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

And lastly, I'm using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(tapSoundID);` to play the sound when a button is tapped.

**TitleScreen.m**

```
#import "TitleScreen.h"
@interface TitleScreen ()
@end

@implementation TitleScreen

- (IBAction)buttonToGameScreen:(id)sender{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(tapSoundID);
}

@end
```

I honestly thought this would work, and Xcode didn't show any warnings or errors until I tried to run the app:

**Build Failed: Apple Mach-O Linker Errors**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_tapSoundID", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[TitleScreen goToGameplay:] in TitleScreen.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea what these errors mean. I'm new to Objective-C/iOS programming, and I've spent hours trying to figure this out on my own but I just can't. Please help.

Comment: Did you mean to have an `@interface` in `TitleScreen.h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extern SystemSoundID tapSoundID` doesn't define `tapSoundID`. It simply means that it is defined somewhere else.

So let's put it in your **AppDelegate.m** file.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

SystemSoundID tapSoundID; // Add this 

@interface AppDelegate ()
@end
```

And I think the link error will just go away.

You can also take a look at this post which explain the use of `extern` very well.

[3 questions about extern used in an Objective-C project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330048/3-questions-about-extern-used-in-a-objective-c-project)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The Mach-O errors go away, but now I'm getting a `Use of undeclared identifier 'tapSoundID'` on the `AudioServicePlaySystemSound(tapSoundID);` line in TitleScreen.h.

Comment: Oh I see now, I got that error thinking I had to delete `extern SystemSoundID tapSoundID;` from the .h file. I added it back to .h and also defined it in the .m file and everything works the way I want it to now! Thanks a ton for the help and the link~

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding how to use global variables.

You declare a global variable without the extern keyword:

```
SystemSoundID tapSoundID;
```

However, you will get "duplicate symbol" linker errors if you simply change the definition to this.  Here's why.

An `#import` directive is like a copy and paste.  After preprocessing, `AppDelegate.m` will look like this:

```
//a few hundred thousand lines of code from UIKit and AudioToolbox here

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

SystemSoundID tapSoundID;

@end


@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Load Tap Sound
    NSURL *tapSoundPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tap" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)tapSoundPath, &tapSoundID);
    return YES;
}

@end
```

and `TitleScreen.m` will look like this:

```
//a few hundred thousand lines of code from UIKit and AudioToolbox here

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

SystemSoundID tapSoundID;

@end

@interface TitleScreen ()
@end

@implementation TitleScreen

- (IBAction)buttonToGameScreen:(id)sender{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(tapSoundID);
}

@end
```

Notice how the project now contains 2 definitions for `tapSoundID`?  That is the  cause the "duplicate symbol" linker error.  If you want a global variable to be accessible  in the whole program, you need to keep the

```
extern SystemSoundID tapSoundID;
```

in `AppDelegate.h`, but you also have to declare the global variable (without `extern`) in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
SystemSoundID tapSoundID;

@implementation AppDelegate
//...
```

The `extern` keyword tells the linker that the global variable is defined in another file.  When you declared the variable only with `extern`, the linker looked for the actual definition, but couldn't find it, causing an "undefined symbol" error.  With the `extern` definition in `AppDelegate.h` *and* the global variable in `AppDelegate.m`, the linker sees the variable in `AppDelegate.m` and makes it accessible to all files that include `AppDelegate.h`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Yuchen mentioned it in his answer above, but it took me a minute to realized I needed both. Your post clarified it further.