# Extern NSString not found by unit tests

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, nsstring

I have some constant strings defined as extern const in header of MyClass.h:

```
extern NSString * const myConstant;
```

and in .m file:

```
NSString * const myConstant = @"Some Constant";
```

And I have a unit test file testing `MyClass`, it could test the class but when I use the constant in the unit test, the linker has a problem:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_myConstant", referenced from:
>   ...

MyClass.m isn't ticked to be part of the Tests target, but I have the "bundler loader" and "test host" set up in Build Settings, so I thought I don't need to have MyClass.m part of Tests target, which works fine for the class itself.

Is there anything I did wrong with the `extern const` that it can't be found by the tests?

Comment: Yeah, you need to target MyClass.m to your test target.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your comments, what I don't understand is that, although the class isn't part of test target, my unit test could find the class, but not the `extern const NSString` defined in the header and the .m file.

Comment: follow this link might be help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330048/3-questions-about-extern-used-in-an-objective-c-project/7330190#7330190