# How to remove "undefined symbol" error in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, undefined-symbol

I declare the variable `ue` in my global.h file as `Extern int ue;`. I have `#include "global.h"`  on all view controllers where I want to use the variable.  If I don't assign a value to `ue` my project builds and runs.  If I assign a value to `ue` I get the following errors and the build fails;

> undefined symbol: _ue
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have searched for the resolution and tried some suggestions, but I keep getting the same errors.  I have declared multiple variables in "global.h" previously and had no issues.

Comment: I think for this basic questions can answer Stackoverlow's AI: https://stackoverflow.com/ai/search

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue and I get "Unknown type name 'Extern'; did you mean 'extern'?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3 questions about extern used in an Objective-C project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330048/3-questions-about-extern-used-in-an-objective-c-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern` modifier means the value is assigned to variable in some other file, so you should not perform it in-place. There are two options to solve your issue.

Option 1: Declare your variable in global.h as static instead of extern.

```
static int ue = 1;
```

Option 2: Create an Obj-C class with global.h and global.m files. Remove all contents (interface/implementation) from both files (you should only keep the `#import` directive in .m file). In your .h file declare an extern variable.

```
extern int ue;
```

In your .m file assign the value:

```
int ue = 1;
```

Comment: Using static worked like a charm.  Thank you so much.